# Asp.MVC + AR + Spatial NHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, activerecord

I have the following setup in a test app I'm trying:

1. ASP.MVC
2. Castle ActiveRecord
3. NHibernate Spatial
4. PostGIS

I know it's a little complicated at first, but here is the deal. I have a controller that works correctly and I have my models. They live in another project, but in the same solution. The code for both is acessible.

I have a simple User model, which BTW, does not have anything spatial. I have one model that uses a Point, but this view and action does not deal with this data.

This is the exception:

NHibernateMappingException {"The constructor being called throws an exception."}

InnerEx: {"A GeometryType column has been declared, but there is no spatial dialect configured"}

Looks like that for the first time I'm debugging (or the first few times), I get an exception telling me that I no spatial dialect could be found. This is weird. Let see some code:

This is my app start method:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Ignition.StartActiveRecord();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

And this is the Ignition.StartActiveRecord:

```
    public static void StartActiveRecord()
    {
        XmlConfigurationSource source = new XmlConfigurationSource(@"path.xml");
        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(source, GetActiveRecordTypes());

        foreach (Configuration cfg in ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder().GetAllConfigurations())
        {
            cfg.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new SpatialAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(cfg));
            //Metadata.AddMapping(cfg, MetadataClass.GeometryColumn);
            //Metadata.AddMapping(cfg, MetadataClass.SpatialReferenceSystem);
        }
    }
```

My web project contains references to all needed libraries:

- NHibernate
- ActiveRecord
- NHibernate Spatial
- NHibernate Spatial (PostGIS)

Help!? this is very annoying and I can't imagine this in a production environment!

Thanks!

Comment: Grr! I have the exact same error, but haven't found a fix yet. The wierd thing is, that I have a lot of sites, but only one fails. The failure seems random also, so it's such a pain! I am starting to suspect IIS or the hosting environment.

Comment: @TigerShark I was only testing, so no harm. I gave up since I could not find resource of configure the darn thing to work with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is "A GeometryType column has been declared, but there is no spatial dialect configured". This means... you need to configure the PostGIS dialect :)

```
<add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Spatial.Dialect.PostGisDialect,NHibernate.Spatial.PostGis" />
```